# How to UNDO dp (or :diffput) in vimdiff, "u" doesn't work

Tags: git, vim, vimdiff

I have started using **vimdiff** as my git difftool, and I have accidentally used the command `dp` (diff put) to put some code to the other file. However, pressing `u` does not undo that, and vim says at the bottom "Already at oldest change"

Undoing `do` (diff obtain) command works perfectly, but strangely not with `dp` !!

Any ideas?

Comment: Which buffer is the current one when you do `u`? With two buffers "a" and "b", and "a" is the current one, doing `dp` changes "b", not "a", so the change must be undone from "b". With the same setup, `do` changes "a" so `u` works in "a" but not in "b".

Comment: @romainl That's right, thanks a lot. That was the reason why it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an attempt  to  explain the issue in a more graphical way.

```
$ echo 1 > a && echo 2 > b
$ vim -d a b
```

`a` is the current buffer:

```
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 2      |
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        |        |
+-[a]----+--b-----+
```

`b` is the target of `dp` so, after `dp`, the current buffer is unchanged and `u` is useless. It is the target that is changed and you can't undo a change in one buffer from another one:

```
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 1      |
|     == dp =>    |
|        |        |
|        |        |
+-[a]----+--b*----+
```

`b` must become current for `u` to work:

```
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 1      |
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        |        |
+--a-----+-[b]*---+ do <C-w>w to change window
```

after `u`:

```
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 2      |
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        |        |
+--a-----+-[b]----+
```

Now, let's go back to the beginning, with `a` being current:

```
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 2      |
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        |        |
+-[a]----+--b-----+
```

After `do`, it is the current buffer that is changed:

```
+--------+--------+
| 2      | 1      |
|     <= do ==    |
|        |        |
|        |        |
+-[a]*---+--b-----+
```

and the change can be undone with `u` without having to change windows:

```
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 2      |
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        |        |
+-[a]----+--b-----+
```